# Discord Python daily

Tags: python, json, discord, discord.py

i want to create a bot with discord.py

I have problems with the daily check. here the users get a little bit of money every day.

I've already added that you can only do it once a day.

But now my question:
How can I display the remaining time when someone enters the command work 2 times in a row

My Code:

```
@client.command(name='work')
@commands.cooldown(1, 86400, commands.BucketType.user)
async def work(ctx):
    await open_account(ctx.author)
    users = await get_bank_data()
    user = ctx.author

    work = random.randrange(1000)
    worktimer = '24h'

    embedpayed = discord.Embed(description=f"**{ctx.author.display_name}**, you got ``{work}``:coin: for your work!"
                               , colour=0xf89474)
    embedpayed.set_author(name='Balance', icon_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
    embedpayed.add_field(name="You can work again in:", value=worktimer)
    embedpayed.set_thumbnail(
        url="https://emojipedia-us.s3.dualstack.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/thumbs/160/twitter/147/money-with-wings_1f4b8.png")


    await ctx.send(embed=embedpayed)

    users[str(user.id)]["wallet"] += work

    with open("mainbank.json", "w") as f:
        json.dump(users, f)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use the datetime library of python
date=datetime.date.today().strftime("%h")
that would gave you the current hour, so you save the hour of execution, and you only would have to make a rest to get the remaining time

Answer (score 0):

You can built in an error handler for that. The error is called `CommandOnCooldown` and can be implemented with `from discord.ext import commands`.

**Have a look at the following code:**

```py
@work.error
async def work_error(ctx, error): 
    if isinstance(error, commands.CommandOnCooldown):
        await ctx.send(f"Please wait {error} seconds.")
```

This will display the remaining time in seconds, converting would be your task then.

*For more information you can also read the [docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=commandoncooldown#discord.ext.commands.CommandOnCooldown)*